# OpenVino model crashes after loading the network

Tags: python, onnx, openvino, non-maximum-suppression

I converted an onnx model to IR using

```
python3 mo_onnx.py --input_model SSD_nms.onnx --input inputs,top_k_per_class,nms_iou,nms_score --input_shape [1,3,224,224],[1],[1],[1]
```

This step worked fine, but when I try to load the network it gives me the following error.

```
ie = IECore() 
net = ie.read_network(model=model_path, weights=weights_path)
print (net.layers)
```

`File "ie_api.pyx", line 1170, in openvino.inference_engine.ie_api.IENetwork.layers.__get__ ValueError: get_shape was called on a descriptor::Tensor with dynamic shape`

I was able to successfully run the same model minus the last NMS layer. Not sure why this fails.
Viewing the IR xml file on netron doesn't show anything off.

The entire layer description which causes trouble:

```
<layer id="351" name="selected_indices" type="NonMaxSuppression" version="opset1">
    <data box_encoding="center" sort_result_descending="0"/>
    <input>
        <port id="0">
            <dim>1</dim>
            <dim>10000</dim>
            <dim>4</dim>
        </port>
        <port id="1">
            <dim>1</dim>
            <dim>2</dim>
            <dim>10000</dim>
        </port>
        <port id="2"/>
        <port id="3"/>
        <port id="4"/>
    </input>
    <output>
        <port id="5" precision="I64">
            <dim>10000</dim>
            <dim>3</dim>
        </port>
    </output>
</layer>
```

Removing the output layer from the IR makes things work normally.

Comment: Can you attach an IR description of the last layer? Especially, `dim` fields. It might shed some light on the issue.The error same from ngraph though. OpenVINO uses ngraph for its graph representation. The error said that one of the dimensions is dynamic.

Comment: @ArtemySkrebkov You were right, it is an issue with the last layer. For reference, it is a NonMaxSuppression layer. If I comment out the layer in the question description everything works fine.

Comment: https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_ops_sort_NonMaxSuppression_1.html

Going from this the output dimensions checks out, do you think a reshape from `[min(num_boxes, max_output_boxes_per_class * num_classes), 3]` to something with `batch_size ...` would help?

Comment: Actually, the layer itself looks good to me. Do not see any issue with it. Hm. There is a similar issue. Please see [link](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Distribution-of-OpenVINO/OPENVINO-ONNX-Model-with-OPEST-11/td-p/1189893?profile.language=es) There is a suggestion to remove the layer and do NMS as a post-processing step.

Comment: Another option I see would be to try `master` branch of openvino framework. Please see https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino It might happen that your issue is fixed in a more recent state of the framework.

Comment: I tried without NMS and getting the raw loc and conf predictions, this works fine. My end goal is to get this model int8 quantized, and for that I might need to setup a custom engine for the accuracy checker, so I thought this might be quicker

Comment: I am using 2020.3 and I realize 2020.4 is released, that might be worth a shot.

Comment: i ran into this exact error and noticed that it was because i was applying a threshold to filter out scores, bboxes prior to passing into NMS, which is of course dynamic. could this be what's happening in your case too?

Comment: Oh yes, that could be it @babasaurusRex So, since the output number of boxes is different at each step, it fails? Also any workarounds?